# Why does the intensity of radiation decrease as the frequency increases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, radiation, thermal-radiation

[image]

[Image Source](http://ne.phys.kyushu-u.ac.jp/seminar/MicroWorld1_E/Part3_E/P34_E/Planck_formula_E.htm)

I am well aware of that what I am going to ask may sound really stupid and easy to answer so forgive my ignorance on the matter. Basically, why does the intensity of radiation decrease as the frequency increases? Why do we have that peak point in the graph below?. And also what the author meant by saying;

> At high frequencies the amount of energy in a quantum, hf, is so large that the high-frequency vibrations can never get going! This is why the blackbody spectrum always becomes small at the high frequency side.

Comment: By considering a set of quantum harmonic oscillators $H = \hbar \omega ( a^{\dagger} a + 1/2)$ and using partition function $Z = Tr( e^{-\beta H} )$ from statistical mechanics, one can derive the distribution

Comment: Two energy scale in this problem: Thermal energy $k_{B} T$ and Energy spacing of the atoms $\hbar \omega$. Higher energy excitation requires more thermal energy. Thus, only small number of atoms can be excited to high energy states. Hence the intensity is small.

Comment: Increase the temperature to $10^{15}$ K and you get a 100 TEV photons or so as the peak, much higher freq. depends on T.